# How to make up a new bitvec out of existing bitvecs?

Tags: z3, z3py

I know in z3 we can extract some bits from one existing bitvec, but right now I have two bitvecs and I want to make a new bitvec based on these two, how can I implement this ?

For example,

```
ah = bitvec("ah", 8)
al = bitvec("al", 8)
```

now I would like to have ax which have ah as its higher 8 bits and al as its lower 8 bits.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Concat function](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/z3.html#-Concat) should do the job.